# In the 34" - 38" screen size range, which 4K wide screen curved monitor has the lowest energy consumption?

Tags: monitors, 4k

I am looking to buy a LCD/LED monitor to attach with my Surface Laptop 5. The monitor should fulfil the following requirements:

- 4K resolution
- screen size between 34 and 38 inches
- one of the lowest power consumption

I am in Australia, and am looking for a low to medium budget monitor, but am open to all suggestions as long as they are under $1000 AUD.

Comment: Do you have a budget requirement?

Comment: @JMY1000 low to medium budget

Comment: Can you give an approximate range in the currency you intend to purchase it in?

Comment: @JMY1000 post updated

Comment: Are you looking for a 16:9 display, or an ultrawide?

Comment: @JMY1000 I believe monitors with more than 34" screen size only come in ultrawide mode.

Comment: There's a great 32" 3840x2160 display which just launched; if that's not for you, then yeah, it'd probably be 3840x1440 34" or 3840x1600 38" displays.

Comment: @JMY1000 which one you mean?

Comment: I had the AW3225QF in mind, which just came out and uses a 3rd-gen QD-OLED panel. Unfortunately it's $1200 USD, so probably out of budget; if you don't want to stretch that far, there are 2nd gen QD-OLED ultrawides that are more in-budget.